# Using box model to contain items within its parent div

Tags: css, parent, children, contain

Using the following HTML and CSS3 rules, I'm trying to make sure that the following criteria are adhered to:

> I have all of the criteria working except for item 1 where the
>   children are exceeding their parent's width. Question: How to keep children within their parent?

1. li items cannot exceed their parent width i.e. 400px
2. img, label, and currency content must be centred vertically within their span
3. currency should not wrap and should always be displayed in full
4. currency should always be displayed as close as possible to the
   label span.
5. the label text should be clamped at 2 lines with ellipsis displayed where it exceeds 2 lines.

Note: Only needs to work in Chrome and Safari webkit-based browsers.

It should look like:

[image]

However, it looks like this at the moment:

[image]

Any ideas?

********************* [JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/philipjmurphy/WDjZ3/3/) ************************

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="img"></span>
        <span class="label">Acclaim</span>
        <span class="currency">(USD 50)</span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <span class="img"></span>
        <span class="label">Acclaim 1 11 111 1111 11111</span>
        <span class="currency">(USD 50)</span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <span class="img"></span>
        <span class="label">Acclaim 1 11 111 1111 11111 2 22222 2222 22222 3 33 333 3333 33333 4 44 444 4444 44444 5 55 555 5555 55555 6 66 666 6666 66666</span>
        <span class="currency">(USD 50)</span>
   </li>
</ul>


ul {
    width: 400px;

    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li {
    display: -webkit-box;

    padding-right: 50px;
}

.label {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;

    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    margin-right: 0.2em;    

    background-color: pink;    
}

.currency {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;

    white-space: nowrap;

    background-color: lightgreen;    
}

.img {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 0.1em;

    background-image:url('data:image/png;base64,iVBOR...);
}
```

Comment: Here's another fiddle that I have working with the flex model, but only on Chrome. It still doesn't work for Safari? http://jsfiddle.net/tUqvG/ - it's a bit of a mix of flex and box models however, as I can't get the ellipsis and line-clamp to work with flex model.

Comment: Flexbox has not replaced the box model. It is just another option for layout.

Comment: You will not get line-clamp to work with box model or flex model in Safari, as text-overflow: ellipsis isn't intended for multi-line text, yours is just a lucky solution on Chrome. :) See http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/textoverflow.html

Comment: You could probably fake text-overflow: ellipsis with a :after selector and content: '…', but it won't be too nice anyways.

Comment: @DavidStorey Removed this statement as not true.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work, providing the price doesn't get wider:

http://jsfiddle.net/WDjZ3/4/

I simply converted the margin-right to pixels so I knew the space taken up by the content other than the label, then added a max-width for the remainder:

```
.label {   
    margin-right: 3px;  
    max-width: 294px;
}
```

if the price or image are variable width, you will need js to read their widths, remove from 400px and add that value to max-width.

Here is an example using JavaScript to dynamically set the max-width: http://jsfiddle.net/WDjZ3/7/

I haven't checked all dimensions, so that should be added to make it fully accurate, otherwise the margins will make the price no longer fit.

I basically checked the width of the other elements:

```
function getWidth(el) {   
    return parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(el,null).getPropertyValue("width"));
}
```

I then removed this width from 400px, and set the maxWidth:

```
for (var i=0; i<imgs.length; i++) {
    var width = 400 - (getWidth(imgs[i]) + getWidth(currencies[i])) + "px"; 
    labels[i].style.maxWidth = width;
}
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for the answer - I appreciate the time that you've put into it. As the price can always be bigger or smaller, the pure CSS solution that you propose will not suffice. I am looking for a solution that uses the box model (or the flex model), see the title of post. I'm really looking for a way do this in CSS alone. As you can see, the CSS that I original wrote is nearly achieving this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve solved this to work without JavaScript. However, it only works in more modern browsers, including Chrome and Opera. It will not work in Safari. It will work in Firefox once it updates to the latest spec. I can probably get it to work in IE10, but I have to look into that more. The ellipsis only works in Chrome/Safari as it is vendor specific.

The demo is at http://jsfiddle.net/uLm92/1/

First of all we want to make the li as a flexbox container and set it to 400px, so the flex items will try to fit that size (more on that later):

```
li {
    /* make all items inside li as flex items */
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    height: 40px;
    max-width: 400px;
 }
```

Now the child items are flex items, the key to getting the label to fit is setting the image and the price to not flex. For the price, we know it wants to always be 40xp wide, so I set the following:

```
.img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;

    -webkit-flex-basis: 40px;
    flex-basis: 40px;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
 }
```

This says that the preferred with id 40px and never make it smaller.

Then we want to also tell the price to never shrink, and to also centre the anonymous box (the content):

```
.currency {

    /* make anonymous box vertically centred */ 
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;

    /* make sure it never shrinks */ 
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
   flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Lastly, we want to also center the label text. As you need the ellipsis hack, I've used the old Flexbox syntax for WebKit. Without using old flexbox, the line-clamp property does not work:

.label {

```
/* need to use old flexbox for line-clamp to work
   it is a *horrible hack* */
display: -webkit-box;
display: flex;

-webkit-line-clamp: 2;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
overflow : hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;

-webkit-box-pack: center;
align-items: center;
```

}

As the other two items will never shrink, the .label element is the only one that can, so it reduces in size if there is no space left.

Comment: Hi dstorey, thanks again for your efforts. However, as stated in the original question ("Note: Only needs to work in Chrome and Safari webkit-based browsers") I need a solution to work in both Chrome and Safari as this needs to work on Android and iOS devices. I think we're hitting a CSS limitation.

Comment: Flexbox is capable of doing what you want, but sadly Safari is not. Its Flexbox implementation is not good enough. It doesn't support things like being able to shrink an element without growing it. You can add more fallbacks to make it mostly work in Safari, but you'd not be able to shrink things correctly. It isn't a CSS limitation; its a Safari limitation.